# Pandas Dataframe retrieve unique column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe. My question is how do I group all the sellers (indicated under sellerUserName) for each date. For example, for any date e.g. 29/03/2018 I want to retrieve a sum of all the unique sellers.

```
   ScrapeDate      sellerUserName
0   29/03/2018            BOB
1   29/03/2018            BOB
2   29/03/2018            BOB
3   29/03/2018            MARY
4   29/03/2018            IAN
5   29/03/2018            ANISA
6   30/03/2018            BOB
7   30/03/2018            BOB
8   30/03/2018            BOB
9   30/03/2018            KARL
10  30/03/2018            KARL
11  30/03/2018            IAN
12  01/04/2018            NGI
13  01/04/2018            NICEE
```

So the output dataframe should be

```
  ScrapeDate       No.of Sellers
0 29/03/2018          4
1 30/03/2018          3
2 01/04/2018          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `nunique`

```
df.groupby('ScrapeDate')['sellerUserName'].nunique()
Out[38]: 
ScrapeDate
01/04/2018    2
29/03/2018    4
30/03/2018    3
Name: sellerUserName, dtype: int64
```